# jquery find returning object(s), how i can call even element?

Tags: jquery, object, for-loop, while-loop, find

how i can handle the objects where given by jquery "find" ?

HTML:

```
<div class="vars"> <input name="test1" /> <input name="test2" /> </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var inputs = $( '.vars' ).find( 'input' );

alert(inputs); // object object
alert(inputs.length) // 2
alert( $(inputs).attr( 'name' ) ); // test1
```

but it changes both background colors if i try

```
$( inputs ).css( 'background', 'green' );
```

okay also i think i can access the obejcts like an array

```
alert( $( inputs[0] ).attr( 'name' ) ); // doesnt work, empty
```

where is my logic error?

Comment: `alert( $( inputs[0] ).attr( 'name' ) );` will return `test1` so you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.eq()` selector to target element based on index:

```
$(inputs).eq(0).css( 'background', 'green' );
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you so much. Works fine.

Comment: As A. Wolff replied you can simply refer to the found array - $(found_array[key]). Just remember to put $ before and use it as jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:even` selector.

```
 $( '.vars' ).find( 'input:even' );
```

Comment: Can you explain me? It works not completly.

I can access now inputs as array but only inputs[0] and inputs[1].. inputs[2] is undefined ( i have now 3 inputs )

Comment: @kaito this returns all `even` elements.. so if you have 3 inputs, since the elements index are 0-based, it will return only two inputs: the input-0 and the input-2 (which are even indexed).